# Distance in metric space p_{1}

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to evaluate distance of point [6,6] and circle $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ in metric space $p_{1}(x,y) = ∑|x_k-y_k|$ (sum metric). I know that I need to count $inf(p_{1}([6,6],X), X $ are points from circle, but I: 1) don't know how to write this as function; 2) can't derivate it to find minimum; 3) don't know if I am thinking in the right way.

Comment: What is $p_1$? A metric in the plane, I gather?

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that was universal symbol for it. I'll write it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's clear the closest point is in the positive quadrant. So we need to minimise $d(x,y) = (6-x) + (6-y)$ (the distance from $(6,6)$ to $(x,y)$ on the circle) under the constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 25$. Of course we can just maximise $x+y$ instead. Intuitively it's clear this should happen on the line $y = x$, which is confirmed by applying [the Lagrange multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), e.g. So the point $(\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}})$ assumes the minimum (which exists by compactness).

Comment: That... not very useful. Maybe it's the problem of our course (we have some basic insight in metric spaces along analysis-2), but I am clearly not ready to understand fully the method you gave me. Is there no other, simplier method to find this minimum?

Comment: I think that you should just "see" that the point on $x=y$ is the closest point. You can justify it using calculus methods, as I did. It's intuitively clear, I think.